# How to open subscriptions page in Play Store in Flutter

Tags: flutter, redirect

I want to edit my active subscription and for this I need to go to the play store.
Forcing the user to open the play store first, and then go to the settings page, and then open subscriptions is not suitable. Can this be done somehow in 1 click (not in browser)?

Options with opening in the browser are not suitable. I need to open the page with all subscriptions (https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions)

I need a redirect link market://...

Thank you!

I tried next packages: url_launcher, store_redirect etc.
Methods like: `

```
final Uri url = 
         Uri.parse('https://apps.apple.com/app/MyAppName/idXXXXX');
          try {
            if (await canLaunch(url.toString())) {
              await launch(url.toString());
            } else {
              throw 'Could not launch $url';
            }
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
          }
```

and

```
launchUrl(Uri.parse('https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions?sku=pro.monthly.testsku&package=com.example.app'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use only this method:

```
final url = Uri.parse('http://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions');
```

Comment: How do you exit the view if you use this method? I am stuck in the subscriptions page and back button does not work